# How to integrate the dotcover HTML reports with sonarqube 4.5?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner, dotcover

I have been struggling with this issue. I have been able to generate the `HTML` reports with the help of `DotCover`. Also, I have given the path of the reports in the Sonar Portal too under `Project Settings--> C# --> CodeCoverage --> DotCoverReportPath` and also in the `Sonar.Properties` file for the particular solution (Mine is a `DotNet` application).

When I run the `Sonar-Runner` it seems  to parse the `HTML` files and also says that Execution success, but however my dashboard on the `Sonar System` shows "No Data" for the coverage.

Please help me out if any of you have faced a similar issue and have been able to figure out the error.

Comment: What version of dotCover are you using? Have you tried opening the html files after they are generated, are the results correct? Have you looked at the sonar-runner log, is there any potentially useful message there?

Comment: Run the sonar-runner with the -X option to get the debug output if you haven't already, it's helped me many a time.

Answer (score 5):

SonarQube requires that the absolute paths of the source files found in the coverage HTML reports to be strictly equal to the absolute paths of the files being analyzed.

This implies that you **cannot** run your tests and collect code coverage on a machine A, transfer the report to machine B, and then run the SonarQube analysis from machine B. From within the same machine, you also **cannot** checkout the code once to run the tests & collect code coverage, and then check it out another time to run the SonarQube analysis.

This is a common case of why code coverage doesn't get imported into SonarQube, but without the logs, it is hard to tell whether this is your case or not.

Comment: For those trying to debug, the full path in the DotCover HTML reports under <html><head><title> of the nnn.html files.